# How to insert nested struct in Elixir?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have the following hierarchy:

```
  BRAND  (1)
    +
    |
    v
CHANNELS (0, N)
    +
    |
    v
 POSTS   (0, N)
```

So each `Brand` has multiple `Channels` which have multiple `Posts`.

The thing is I want to insert a single `Post` with the given `Channel` and `Brand` names.

So what I need to do is to:

1. Create a `Post`
2. Find or Create a `Channel`
3. Associate the `Post` with the Channel
4. Find or Create a `Brand`
5. Associate the `Channel` with the `Brand`

My `find_or_update` function is:

```
Repo.insert(
  %Brand{name: "name"},
  on_conflict: [set: [name: name]], 
  conflict_target: :name, 
  returning: [:id]
)
```

which will give me an `id` in case.

What is the best way to do all of that?

Comment: Are these many to many, or many to one relationships? Also, why not start with the brand and work your way down?

Comment: As you can see, they are not may to many. `BRAND (1) - (0, N) CHANNELS (1) - (0, N) POSTS`

Comment: I think you will benefit from using [`build_assoc/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.html#build_assoc/3). But again, why not start with brand and work your way down to the post?

Comment: `build_assoc/3` would work if you would use it for the thing you have already - you need to have `brand` to associate it `channel` and then with `post`